# A question on cardinal arithmetic

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

The following problem is exercise 6.12 of Thomas Jech's "Set Theory" and i'd be thankful for some hints:
First we define $ \kappa^{\lt \kappa} $ and $ 2^{\lt \kappa} $:
$ \kappa^{\lt \kappa} = \lim_{\alpha \rightarrow \kappa} \kappa^\alpha $
$ 2^{\lt \kappa} = \lim_{\alpha \rightarrow \kappa} 2^\alpha $
The statement: If $\kappa$ is a regular and limit cardinal,  then $\kappa^{\lt \kappa} = 2^{\lt \kappa}$.
Edit I:
The $\kappa^{\lt \kappa} \ge 2^{\lt \kappa}$ part is quite easy since every $\kappa^\alpha$ is greater than or equal to $2^\alpha$ then the suprema must be greater than or equal to, aswell. The tricky part is proving  $\kappa^{\lt \kappa} \le 2^{\lt \kappa}$.

Comment: I'd be grateful if someone told me the reason for the downvote.

Comment: It's probably a show-your-work kind of downvote.

Comment: Oh. Thanks. But the thing is i have no clue on how to start.

Comment: Well, for example, can you show that $2^{< \kappa} \leq \kappa^{< \kappa}$? That would be a start, at least.

Comment: Yes. That is easy since every $2^\alpha$ is less than or equal to $\kappa^\alpha$ then the suprema must be less than or equal to, aswell.

Comment: Hint: 1) $\lambda^\lambda = 2^\lambda$ in general. 2) $\kappa$ is regular. Use this to write $\kappa^\alpha$ for $\alpha < \kappa$ a bit differently.

Comment: The only thing i can think of is $ \kappa^\alpha = \Sigma_{\zeta \lt \kappa} \zeta^\alpha$ which doesn't seem to be helpful.

Comment: @ShervinSorouri Another hint: $\zeta^\alpha \leq \zeta^\zeta = 2^{\zeta}$ once $\zeta \geq \alpha$, so $\sum_{\zeta < \kappa} \zeta^\alpha \leq $...

Comment: I think i got it, we will show that each $\kappa^\alpha$ is less than or equal to $2^{\lt \kappa}$ so their suprema is also less than or equal to $2^{\lt \kappa}$. [Pending]

Comment: For each $\alpha$ we have $\kappa^\alpha = \lim_{\zeta \rightarrow \kappa} \zeta^\alpha = \sup\{ \zeta^\alpha : \zeta \lt \kappa \} = \sup\{ \zeta^\alpha : \alpha \lt \zeta \lt \kappa \} \le \sup\{ \zeta^\zeta : \alpha \lt \zeta \lt \kappa \} = \sup\{ 2^\zeta : \zeta \lt \kappa \} = 2^{\lt \kappa}$

Comment: Is this approach correct? @Jonathan Something that bothers me with this approach is that it seems like we didn't use the premise that k is a limit cardinal.

Comment: @ShervinSorouri For $\kappa$ successor $\kappa^\alpha = \lim_{\zeta \to \kappa} \zeta^\alpha$ is not correct. $\kappa^\alpha = \sum_{\zeta < \kappa} \zeta^\alpha \leq... \leq \kappa \cdot 2^{<\kappa}$! In case $\kappa$ is limit we have that $\kappa \cdot 2^{<\kappa} = 2^{<\kappa}$.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much, kind sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notation: $^d e$ is the set of functions from $d$ to $e$.

Depending on your choice of definitions, $\omega$ could be a regular limit cardinal. In this Q, $\kappa=\omega$ is a trivial case, so assume $\kappa$ is uncountable.

If $a< k$ and $f\in ^a \kappa$ then $f\in ^a b$ for some $b<\kappa.$ For example if $b=\sup \{f(x):x\in a\}+1$ then $b<\kappa$ because (i) $\kappa$ is a limit ordinal, and (ii)  $cf(\kappa)=\kappa>|a|\geq|\{f(x):x\in a\}|.$

So $\kappa^{<\kappa}=|\cup \{^a \kappa:a\in \kappa\}|=|\cup \{^a b:a,b\in \kappa\}|.$

If $c$ is an infinite cardinal ordinal then $c^c=2^c.$

For $a,b \in \kappa$ let $c=\max (|a|,|b|,\omega).$ Then $c< k$ and $|^a b|=|b|^{|a|}\leq c^c=2^c.$

The rest should be easy.